# Powershell open window (from Java.Runtime.exec)

Tags: java, powershell, runtime, exec

simple Question:

i want to call the powershell with some commands from java. But the Problem is that no Window appears. i want that the window with the Powershell appears.

```
String[] str= {
"powershell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "echo", "hallo"
}

[...]

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);

[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

```
String[] str= { "cmd",  "/c", "start", "powershell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "echo", "hallo" };
```

Comment: initial `cmd /c` - is what i've been lacking.. ))