# How to run a .ps1 file in PowerShell_ISE.exe through Java

Tags: java, eclipse, powershell, scripting

So I am creating a GUI in java that launches a variety of different scripts through powershell. I have been able to write a command that opens the .ps1 file in powershellISE, but the script doesn't actually run. My code is as follows:

```
String [] str = {"cmd", "/c" "start", "powershell_ise.exe", "-file", "myPath"};
try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I found this question to be helpful:

[Powershell open window (from Java.Runtime.exec)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530774/powershell-open-window-from-java-runtime-exec)

But it did not solve my issue of actually *running* the script

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why through ISE?

Comment: Some of the scripts require editing an Excel document prior to running them so some will open in ISE and then be ran after the document is updated. Would it be easier to launch through powershell.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE) is a graphical host application that enables you to read, write, run, debug, and test scripts.

If you want to run scripts you know work, you might try replacing `powershell_ise.exe` with `powershell.exe`. [How to run powershell in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436405/how-to-run-powershell-in-cmd) should help.

Comment: Thanks! The following line ended up working out for me:    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start powershell -file " + pathToFileInQuotes);